# Android app, device (Galaxy Mini) not supported

Tags: android, galaxy

My android app is not supported on GalaxyMini (among others). When I look at the features needed by the app (copy/pasted from google play admin console), all seems to be there on the GalaxyMini. I don't understand why it would not be served on GalaxyMini.

NativePlateform armeabi seems not to be the problem as I've tried with a previous apk without this feature requirement and the GalaxyMini is still not supported.

Any idea?

```
Localized to: default, Dutch, French
Permissions: android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
Features: android.hardware.camera, android.hardware.camera.autofocus, android.hardware.location, android.hardware.location.gps, android.hardware.screen.landscape, android.hardware.screen.portrait, android.hardware.touchscreen
No main expansion file
No expansion patch file
[8/31/12 10:00:14 AM] : API level: 7-16+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all
Native platforms: armeabi
```

Comment: Try running aapt in platform-tools with the command 'aapt dump badging path_to_apk.apk' and posting the output here
This will output any implicit requirements your requested Features may have caused

Comment: This is now redundant since you found the answer, but a useful tip for the future <:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The galaxy mini does not have `android.hardware.camera.autofocus`. Its camera is fixed focus. If the feature is not an absolute requirement in your app then you could add `android:required="false"` to its `uses-feature` tag.

Comment: Ah thanks :) I was posting my answer at the same time. I should have go to launch instead of trying to solve it myself. Thanks a lto anyway!

Answer (score 1):

After many tries, the problem was "android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
GalaxyMini is supposed to support autofocus ont the tech specs. I really wish that the google play developper console tells us which of the manifest settings are used to exclude a device, that would save us a lot of time.

So I just added the following line in the manifest to make it available to galaxy mini (and about 300 other devices!) :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```